# Redirect ErrorDocument custom page (500,503) with mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, web-applications, ibmhttpserver, web-administration

I want to use a custom page on 500 & 503 errorducument on IBM HTTP Server as well as shortener URL also using Rewrite that code for shorten URL (WCS).

Here are the rules I'm using:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} /en/store(.*)

RewriteRule  ^/en/store(.*) $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} /((?!wcsstore/)(?!search/)(?!cont/)(?!cons/)(?!cs/)(?!wcs/)(?!cache/)(?!webapp/)(?!swagger/)(?!solr/))(.*) 

RewriteRule ^/((?!wcsstore/)(?!search/)(?!cont/)(?!cons/)(?!cs/)(?!wcs/)(?!cache/)(?!webapp/)(?!swagger/)(?!solr/))(.*) /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/store/$2 [PT,L]
```

When I am not Using shorten URL code then ErrorDocument 500 /500.html Custom page is working fine. but when I am Using shorten URL code then ErrorDocument 500 /500.html Custom page is not working. And when I am using String like ErrorDocument 500 "Server in a problem so We will be back shortly" is working both condition, with shorten URL code or without shorten URL code.

Comment: Please add a question to your question. What do those rules have to do with the topic?

Comment: I want to use a custom page on 500 & 503 errorducument on IBM HTTP Server as well as shortener URL also using Rewrite that code for shorten URL (WCS)

Comment: When I am not Using shorten URL code then                               ErrorDocument 500 /500.html Custom page is working fine.                    but when I am Using shorten URL code then ErrorDocument 500 /500.html Custom page is not working.     And when I am using String like ErrorDocument 500 "Server in a problem so We will be back shortly" is working both condition, with shorten URL code or without shorten URL code.

Comment: formatted to code block and pulled OP's comments into question to help phrase a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final RewriteRule matches /500.html so it's rewritten. I'd suggest scrapping adding an additional RewriteCond that simply handles the error doc URL's, rather than adding more difficult to read negative lookaheads.

Note: the existing condition already looks redundant:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /((?!wcsstore/)(?!search/)(?!cont/)(?!cons/)(?!cs/)(?!wcs/)(?!cache/)(?!webapp/)(?!swagger/)(?!solr/))(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUET_URI} ^/\d\d\d.html
RewriteRule ^/((?!wcsstore/)(?!search/)(?!cont/)(?!cons/)(?!cs/)(?!wcs/)(?!cache/)(?!webapp/)(?!swagger/)(?!solr/))(.*) /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/store/$2 [PT,L]
```